# Как написать возврат NpgsqlCommand из фукнции с использованием пула соединений?

Tags: c#

Есть функция типа:

```
NpgsqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}
```

Я ее использую в виде:

```
using (var connection = GetConnection())
{
    using (var q = new NpgsqlCommand {Connection = connection})
    {
        q.CommandText = "SELECT ... FROM ...;";
        q.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

Все работает, но хочу сократить код до

```
using (var q = GetCommand("SELECT ... FROM ...;"))
{
    q.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Возникает вопрос, как написать GetCommand. Если тупо возвращать созданную команду, то соединение не закрывается и пул в итоге переполняется. Если в Disposed команды добавить NpgsqlCommand.Connection.Dispose(), то к этому моменту Connection = null и закрывать нечего.

Может туплю на ровном месте, но вот как эту GetCommand написать:

```
NpgsqlCommand GetCommand(string commandText)
{
    return new NpgsqlCommand(commandText, GetConnection());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если хранить соответствие команда-соединение, то работает так...

```
public static NpgsqlCommand GetCommand(string commandText = "")
{
    lock (_instance._locker)
    {
        var conn = GetConnection();
        var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(commandText, conn);
        cmd.Disposed += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (_instance._pool.TryGetValue(o as NpgsqlCommand ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(), out var c))
            {
                c.Close();
            }
        };
        _instance._pool[cmd] = conn;
        return cmd;
    }
}
```